How to calculate stock with price using FIFO method
I would like to ask how to use the FIFO method with MySQL 8 to generate the expected result as follow.
dbfiddle



product_id
type
quantity
price
operation_date




1
PURCHASE
10
100
2024-08-01


2
PURCHASE
25
80
2024-08-02


2
SALE
20
140
2024-08-03


1
SALE
7
120
2024-08-03


2
PURCHASE
20
90
2024-08-04


3
PURCHASE
40
50
2024-08-05


3
PURCHASE
20
40
2024-08-06


3
PURCHASE
20
20
2024-08-07


2
SALE
20
160
2024-08-07


3
SALE
50
150
2024-08-07


3
SALE
20
160
2024-08-08


1
PURCHASE
10
80
2024-08-09



I need to calculate stock value for each product.
Expected Output



product_id
Stock Value




1
1100


2
450


3
200



To accurately calculate the current stock value, we need to use the First-In-First-Out (FIFO) method. The FIFO method means that the items bought first are sold first, so the remaining stock should be valued at the most recent purchase prices.
I have tried many queries but I am not getting what I am looking for.
Stock Value Calculation Example for Product Id 1 (manual calculation)
Purchase 10 qty at price 100 on 2024-08-01 so that stock value is 1000
after 2024-08-01, I sold 7 qty at 120 so now my stock value will be 300 as the purchase price was 100.
On 2024-08-09 I purchased another 10 qty at 80.
Now the final stock value for me is:
3  qty @ 100 = 300 (left from a previous purchase)
10 qty @ 80  = 800 
------------------- 
13 qty      = 1100 stock value

Stock Value Calculation Example for Product Id 2 (manual calculation)
Purchase 25 qty at price 80 
Sell     20 qty at 
---------------------------
          5 qty remaining from first purchase at 80 price
Purchase 20 qty at price 90
---------------------------
   Total 25 qty (5 qty @ 80 price and 20 qty @ 90 price)
Sell     20 qty (using fifo method 5 deduct from first purchase and 15 deduct from second purchase)
---------------------------
Remaining 5 qty @ 90 price 
So, the stock value is 5 * 90 = 450

Stock Value Calculation Example for Product Id 3 (manual calculation)
Purchase  40 qty at price 50
Purchase  20 qty at price 40
Purchase  20 qty at price 20
----------------------------
-         50 qty (sell)
----------------------------
Remaining 30 qty (using FIFO 10 qty left at 40 price and 20 left at 20 price
----------------------------
-         20 qty (sell)
----------------------------
Remaining 10 qty (using FIFO 10 qty left at 20 price)
So, stock value is 10 qty * 20 price = 200


NOTE: IF CHANGING THE STRUCTURE OF TABLE CAN HELP IN SOLVING THIS
PROBLEM THEN ALSO SUGGEST.


Update 1:
Updated DBFIDDLE



product_id
type
quantity
price
operation_date




1
PURCHASE
10
100
2024-08-01


2
PURCHASE
25
80
2024-08-02


2
SALE
20
140
2024-08-03


1
SALE
7
120
2024-08-03


2
PURCHASE
20
90
2024-08-04


3
PURCHASE
40
50
2024-08-05


3
PURCHASE
20
40
2024-08-06


3
PURCHASE
20
20
2024-08-07


2
SALE
20
160
2024-08-07


3
SALE
50
150
2024-08-07


3
SALE
20
160
2024-08-08


1
PURCHASE
10
80
2024-08-09


3
SALE RETURN
20
160
2024-08-10


2
PURCHASE RETURN
4
120
2024-08-11



I need to calculate the stock value for each product.
Expected Output after including sale return and purchase return



product_id
Stock Value




1
1100


2
90


3
800



To accurately calculate the current stock value, we need to use the First-In-First-Out (FIFO) method. The FIFO method means that the items bought first are sold first, so the remaining stock should be valued at the most recent purchase prices.
For Sale return cases the Item stock sold last should settle first.
For Purchase return cases the Item stock purchased last should settle first.
Stock Value Calculation Example for Product Id 1 (manual calculation)
Purchase 10 qty at a price 100 on 2024-08-01 so that stock value is 1000
after 2024-08-01, I sold 7 qty at 120 so now my stock value will be 300 as the purchase price was 100.
On 2024-08-09 I purchased another 10 qty at 80.
Now the final stock value for me is:
3  qty @ 100 = 300 (left from a previous purchase)
10 qty @ 80  = 800 
------------------- 
13 qty      = 1100 stock value

Stock Value Calculation Example for Product Id 2 (manual calculation)
Purchase 25 qty at price 80 
Sell     20 qty at 
---------------------------
          5 qty remaining from first purchase at 80 price
Purchase 20 qty at price 90
---------------------------
   Total 25 qty (5 qty @ 80 price and 20 qty @ 90 price)
Sell     20 qty (using fifo method 5 deduct from first purchase and 15 deduct from second purchase)
---------------------------
Remaining 5 qty @ 90 price 
Purchase Return 4 @ whatever price  (debit in stock)
---------------------------
Remaining 1 qty @ 90 price
So, the stock value is 1 * 90 = 90

Stock Value Calculation Example for Product Id 3 (manual calculation)
Purchase  40 qty at price 50
Purchase  20 qty at price 40
Purchase  20 qty at price 20
----------------------------
-         50 qty (sell)
----------------------------
Remaining 30 qty (using FIFO 10 qty left at 40 price and 20 left at 20 price
----------------------------
-         20 qty (sell)
----------------------------
Remaining 10 qty (using FIFO 10 qty left at 20 price)
+         20 qty (sell return) (credit in stock)
----------------------------
Remaining 30 qty (using LIFO 20 qty @ 20 and 10 @ at 40)
So, the stock value is (20 * 20 = 400) +  (10 * 40 = 400) = 800


Provide detailed explanations for the output, at least for one row. provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (see Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3).

@Akina I have updated the question and added DBFiddle Also. Please help me if you have any solution.

Pls, add row (1, 'PURCHASE', '10', 80, '2024-08-09') to fiddle and refresh link.

@ValNik Link updated.

@user1924932 hope that helps

To solve the problem, it does not matter, however, in the 'PURCHASE RETURN' operation, the price must be the same as in the corresponding 'PURCHASE' operation, or correspond to the balance(stock) price on the date of return.

Here is the query to calculate the stock value for each product using FIFO:
The recursive common table expression (inventory_cte) processes purchases and sales. For each sale, it calculates the remaining quantities and the cost of the remaining inventory.
Summarize the stock values by summing up the total cost for each product where remaining quantity is greater than zero.
dbfiddle
WITH RECURSIVE inventory_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        product_id, 
        type, 
        quantity, 
        price, 
        operation_date,
        quantity AS remaining_quantity,
        price * quantity AS total_cost
    FROM inventory
    WHERE type = 'PURCHASE'
    
    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        i.product_id, 
        i.type, 
        i.quantity, 
        i.price, 
        i.operation_date,
        CASE 
            WHEN inv.remaining_quantity >= i.quantity THEN inv.remaining_quantity - i.quantity
            ELSE 0 
        END AS remaining_quantity,
        CASE 
            WHEN inv.remaining_quantity >= i.quantity THEN inv.total_cost - (i.quantity * inv.price)
            ELSE inv.total_cost 
        END AS total_cost
    FROM inventory_cte inv
    JOIN inventory i ON inv.product_id = i.product_id
    WHERE i.type = 'SALE' AND i.quantity <= inv.remaining_quantity
)

SELECT 
    product_id,
    SUM(total_cost) AS stock_value
FROM inventory_cte
WHERE remaining_quantity > 0
GROUP BY product_id;


My dear friend, sorry to say but your query is returning wrong output.

@user1924932 your feedback should include more detailed explanation as to what the query produces for you vs what you expect it to produce. In uts current format, your feedback is not particularly helpful.

@Shadow the query of Busra Ecem Sakar
Returning wrong output.
Stock value for product_id 1 should be 1100
and product_id 2 should be 450
and product_id 3 should be 200
but the above query is returning
product_id 1 -> 1300,  product_id 2 -> 4600 and product_id 3 -> 4200

After manual calculation, Product 1 has a final stock value of 1100. For Product 2, starting with 25 qty at 80, and after selling 20 qty and buying 20 qty at 90, all remaining stock was sold off, leaving a final stock value of 0. Similarly, for Product 3, with purchases totaling 80 qty at varying prices and sales of 70 qty, all stock was depleted, resulting in a final stock value of 0. Thus, the final stock values are: Product 1: 1100, Product 2: 0, Product 3: 0, could you please check? I will edit query based on your response.

@BusraEcemSakar I have updated manual calculation for each product in question. Please check and help me.

So the best approach might be using CTE_Operations: creating a CTE (CTE_Operations) that adjusts the quantity based on whether the operation is a SALE or PURCHASE. For sales, the quantity is negated to reflect stock reduction. See docs for reference
CTE_RunningStock: CTE calculates the running stock for each product. usually with a window function to accumulate the stock after each transaction (SUM(adjusted_quantity) OVER (...)).
Finally CTE_StockAfterSales calculates the remaining stock after sales have been applied.
Here is a code snippet:
 WITH CTE_Transactions AS (
    SELECT 
        product_id,
        type,
        quantity,
        price,
        operation_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY operation_date) AS rn
    FROM test
),
CTE_Sales AS (
    SELECT 
        product_id, 
        quantity,
        operation_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY operation_date) AS rn
    FROM CTE_Transactions
    WHERE type = 'SALE'
),
CTE_Purchases AS (
    SELECT 
        product_id,
        quantity,
        price,
        operation_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY operation_date) AS rn
    FROM CTE_Transactions
    WHERE type = 'PURCHASE'
),
CTE_StockAfterSales AS (
    SELECT
        p.product_id,
        p.quantity AS purchase_quantity,
        p.price,
        p.operation_date,
        s.quantity AS sale_quantity,
        p.quantity - COALESCE(s.quantity, 0) AS remaining_quantity,
        p.price * (p.quantity - COALESCE(s.quantity, 0)) AS stock_value
    FROM 
        CTE_Purchases p
    LEFT JOIN 
        CTE_Sales s
    ON 
        p.product_id = s.product_id AND p.rn = s.rn
    WHERE 
        p.quantity - COALESCE(s.quantity, 0) > 0
)
SELECT 
    product_id,
    SUM(stock_value) AS stock_value
FROM 
    CTE_StockAfterSales
GROUP BY 
    product_id
ORDER BY 
    product_id;



See example.
We join purchases and sales by ranges.
Test data



oper_id
product_id
type
quantity
price
operation_date




1
1
PURCHASE
10
100
2024-08-01


4
1
SALE
7
120
2024-08-03


12
1
PURCHASE
10
80
2024-08-09


2
2
PURCHASE
25
80
2024-08-02


3
2
SALE
20
140
2024-08-03


5
2
PURCHASE
20
90
2024-08-04


9
2
SALE
20
160
2024-08-07


6
3
PURCHASE
40
50
2024-08-05


7
3
PURCHASE
20
40
2024-08-06


8
3
PURCHASE
20
20
2024-08-07


10
3
SALE
50
150
2024-08-07


11
3
SALE
20
160
2024-08-08



JOIN schema:
For product_id 1
Purchases: 10        10     
Running pur|1------10|11----20|
Running sal|1----7|
Sales :    7         

For product_id 2
          25     20     
Purchases:|1---25|26--45|
Sales    :|1--20|21--40|
          20    20

For product_id 3
Purchases: 40        20     20
Running pur|1------40|41----60|61-----80|
Running sal|1---------50|51----70|
Sales :    50           20

After JOIN and Before grouping



product_id
oper_id
type
pQty
pPrice
pDate
soper_id
stype
sQty
sprice
sDate
sold
purchaseSold
purchaseRest




1
1
PURCHASE
10
100
2024-08-01
4
SALE
7
120
2024-08-03
7
7
3


1
12
PURCHASE
10
80
2024-08-09
null
null
null
null
null
0
0
10


2
2
PURCHASE
25
80
2024-08-02
3
SALE
20
140
2024-08-03
20
25
0


2
2
PURCHASE
25
80
2024-08-02
9
SALE
20
160
2024-08-07
5
25
0


2
5
PURCHASE
20
90
2024-08-04
9
SALE
20
160
2024-08-07
15
15
5


3
6
PURCHASE
40
50
2024-08-05
10
SALE
50
150
2024-08-07
40
40
0


3
7
PURCHASE
20
40
2024-08-06
10
SALE
50
150
2024-08-07
10
20
0


3
7
PURCHASE
20
40
2024-08-06
11
SALE
20
160
2024-08-08
10
20
0


3
8
PURCHASE
20
20
2024-08-07
11
SALE
20
160
2024-08-08
10
10
10



with ps as( -- calculate running total ranges for purchases and sales
  select oper_id,product_id, type, quantity, price, operation_date
   ,sum(quantity)
      over(partition by product_id,type order by operation_date,oper_id)-quantity+1 vFrom
   ,sum(quantity)
      over(partition by product_id,type order by operation_date,oper_id) vTo
  from test
)
,purchases_and_sales as( -- join purchases and sales by running total ranges
select p.oper_id,p.product_id,p.type,p.quantity pQty,p.price pPrice
  ,p.operation_date pDate,p.vFrom pFrom,p.vTo pTo
  ,s.oper_id soper_id,s.type stype,s.quantity sQty,s.price sprice
  ,s.operation_date sDate,s.vFrom sFrom,s.vTo sTo
from ps p
left join ps s on p.product_id=s.product_id and p.type='PURCHASE' and s.type='SALE'
   and ( s.vFrom between p.vFrom and p.vTo -- intersections
      or s.vTo between p.vFrom and p.vTo 
      or p.vFrom between s.vFrom and s.vTo
      or p.vTo between s.vFrom and s.vTo 
     )where p.type='PURCHASE'
)
,moves as(
select product_id,oper_id,type,pQty,pPrice,pDate
  ,soper_id,stype,sQty,sprice,sDate
  ,coalesce(least(pTo,sTo)-greatest(pFrom,sFrom)+1,0) sold
from purchases_and_sales 
)
,balance as(
select product_id,oper_id,type,pQty,pPrice,pDate
  ,soper_id,stype,sQty,sprice,sDate,sold 
  ,sum(sold)over(partition by product_id,oper_id)purchaseSold
  ,pQty-sum(sold)over(partition by product_id,oper_id)purchaseRest
from moves
)
select product_id
  ,sum(purchaseRest*pPrice) pStockRest
from balance
group by product_id
order by product_id ;


Result is



product_id
stockRest




1
1100


2
450


3
200



fiddle
and - there more test data.
Column oper_id int auto_increment ,PRIMARY KEY (oper_id) is added to table DDL for clarity and to determine the order of the rows when the date matches. Any other way to determine the order of rows with a single date can be used.

the query is working perfectly. But when we add sale return and purchase return in data the query generates wrong output.

What is sale return and purchase return? You shold explin this in question.

Please check I have updated the question and explain what is sale return and purchase return and how that should affect on stock value.

This kind of logic is usually handled in code. You can try this：
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS
WITH cte_test AS (
SELECT 
product_id,
TYPE,
quantity,
price,
operation_date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY operation_date) AS rn
FROM test
),
cte_sale AS (
SELECT
product_id,
SUM(quantity) AS q
FROM cte_test
WHERE TYPE = 'SALE'
GROUP BY product_id
)
SELECT 
t.product_id,
t.TYPE,
t.quantity,
t.price,
t.operation_date,
s.q AS q
FROM cte_test t
LEFT JOIN cte_sale s ON t.product_id = s.product_id;
SELECT a.product_id,SUM(a.quantity * a.price) AS stock_value FROM (
SELECT
product_id,
price,
case when product_id != @pre then @q := q ELSE @q END AS q_new,
if(TYPE = 'SALE',0,if(quantity > @q,quantity - @q,0)) AS quantity,
if(TYPE = 'SALE',0,if(quantity > @q,@q := 0,@q := @q - quantity)) AS l,
@pre := product_id
FROM temp_table,(SELECT @q := 0,@pre) tmp
ORDER BY product_id,operation_date) a GROUP BY a.product_id;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;

